# Bucle para obtener muchos gráficos - R

Tags: r, bucles, graph

Utilizando RStudio, estoy tratando de obtener muchos gráficos de un gran conjunto de datos de puntos. Si intento crear un gráfico con todos ellos tengo tantos puntos que realmente no puedo ver nada. Por lo tanto, quería crear muchos gráficos con 25 puntos de datos más o menos y luego ponerlos en pantalla al mismo tiempo con ggarrange.
Soy bastante nuevo en R y he intentado crear un bucle, pero me está dando problemas y no sé cómo conseguir lo que quiero.

Las imágenes corresponden al código que estoy probando, la segunda es una que hice manualmente poniendo un intervalo de [1:25] y como quiero que se vean todos y la última imagen es lo que obtengo con todo el conjunto de datos.

Lo que quiero hacer después de tener las imágenes, es obtener todas las ecuaciones y obtener una general para todo el conjunto de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hi Pepa, welcome to ES SE. This is a Spanish site, so if you speak Spanish please translate your question for giving you an answer. BTW, you can add alpha to point fill color or try a density plot. Cheers